# GitLab CI and GCP default project

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci

I was expecting my spring boot tests to fail in my GitLab ci pipeline because I hadn't setup any GCP credentials, but they work!

I notice in my logs
org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.core.GcpContextAutoConfiguration - The default project ID is gitlab-ci-plan-free-4-3ba81e

I presume this must mean that gitlab have their own GCP account for this purpose and this is why my tests pass?

Comment: Where is running Gitlab CI? (at least the workers)

Comment: I am using the built-in default gitlab runner

Comment: You have something in your configuration. You can't have access to your project without any permissions. Do you have service account key files in your secrets? Are you the platform admin?

Comment: Are you using any GCP product you are aware of?